# data.table: field in row with first ocurrence

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to explore an elegant (one-liner) solution for a `data.table` grouping

I have a `data.table` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dt.master <- data.table(user = c(1000, 1002, 2008, 3005, 1000, 1002, 1002),
                    target = c(50000, 50004, 50501, 50001, 50000, 50000, 50004),
                    channel = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C"),
                    date = c(dmy("10/02/2018"), dmy("11/04/2018"), dmy("14/03/2018"), dmy("02/03/2018"), dmy("05/01/2018"), dmy("08/05/2018"), dmy("05/03/2018")))
```

That is:

```
   user target channel       date
1: 1000  50000       A 2018-02-10
2: 1002  50004       B 2018-04-11
3: 2008  50501       C 2018-03-14
4: 3005  50001       A 2018-03-02
5: 1000  50000       B 2018-01-05
6: 1002  50000       A 2018-05-08
7: 1002  50004       C 2018-03-05
```

I would like to know, for each group of `(user, target)`, the channel of the first ocurrence, and add it to the dt.master. This is:

```
   user target channel       date first_channel
1: 1000  50000       A 2018-02-10             B
2: 1000  50000       B 2018-01-05             B
3: 1002  50000       A 2018-05-08             A
4: 1002  50004       B 2018-04-11             C
5: 1002  50004       C 2018-03-05             C
6: 2008  50501       C 2018-03-14             C
7: 3005  50001       A 2018-03-02             A
```

Currently, I am doing it in two steps:

1. First, I extract the rows of the first ocurrence

   ```
   dt.result <- dt.master[dt.master[, .(first_interest = .I[which.min(date)]), by = c("user", "target")]$first_interest,]
   ```
2. And, afterwards, I merge it with `dt.master`

   ```
   setnames(dt.result, "channel", "first_channel")
   dt.master <- merge(dt.master, dt.result[, .(user, target, first_channel)],
                   by.x = c("user", "target"), by.y = c("user", "target"),
                   all.x = T, all.y = F)
   ```

**Is there a way to do it with no merges?** I believe there must be a solution modifying the first line, but I cannot find it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update by reference by groups as follows:

```
dt.master[, first_channel := channel[which.min(date)], keyby=.(user, target)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt.master[,date:=as.character(date)]
dt.master[,date:=as.numeric(gsub("-","",date))]
dt.master<-dt.master[order(user,date)]
dt.master[,firt_occ:=channel[1],by=c("user")]
```

Comment: Just sort your data.table first

Comment: There is a `setorder` function for ordering in place

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I know, I thought for this example it did not matter!